# Out of memory decrypting large files in PHP with phpseclib

Tags: php, aes, phpseclib

I'm trying to write a program that decrypts AES files on the fly with phpseclib. 
Files are large, so I get an out of memory error if I use file_get_contents($f) or fread(filesize($f)) to read the input file.

For some reason, a loop like this is creating corrupted output files. WHY!? =(

For example, an input file of size 296,155,408 bytes comes out with 18,805,826 bytes. NOTE: It works if the entire file can be read in one iteration of the loop.

```
define('MY_BUFFER_SIZE', 128 * 1024);
$sessionKey = '....';

$filenameIn = $argv[1];
$fileIn = fopen($filenameIn, 'rb');
$filenameOut = dirname($argv[1]) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($argv[1], '.tar.gz') . '-decrypted.tar.gz';
$fileOut = fopen($filenameOut, 'wb');

// Setup cipher for continuous buffering and copy between files.
$aesCipher = new Crypt_AES(CRYPT_AES_MODE_CBC);
$aesCipher->setKey($sessionKey);
$aesCipher->setIV("\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00");
$aesCipher->enableContinuousBuffer();
while (!feof($fileIn)) {
    $packet = fread($fileIn, MY_BUFFER_SIZE); // @TODO: Streaming not working.
    fwrite($fileOut, $aesCipher->decrypt($packet));
}

fclose($fileIn);
fclose($fileOut);
```

Comment: Do you understand what that "CBC" means? Also, can you describe more precisely what you mean by "corrupted"?

Comment: Cipher block chaining. :) That's why I've enabled the continuous buffer. Thought that was for this type of use case. "Corrupted" means they aren't valid. I'm working with .tgz binaries so I can't say beyond the fact that they can't be opened.

Comment: Do you mean that you encrypt them and then decrypt them and they're corrupt? If so, can you show both the encrypting code and the decrypting code? (unless it's the same)

Comment: No. They are already encrypted externally. I am trying to read the encrypted file, decrypt it, and save it with a new name. Adding a bit more code around the snippet to provide more context...

Comment: Most likely, the encrypted file doesn't have precisely the structure this code expects.

Comment: It works fine if the files are small and only one loop iteration is required.

Comment: That's completely consistent with my diagnosis.

Comment: Maybe disable padding? eg. `$aesCipher->disablePadding()`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @neubert!
What was required was adding:

```
$aesCipher->disablePadding()
```

This works:

```
// Setup cipher for continuous buffering and copy between files.
$aesCipher = new Crypt_AES(CRYPT_AES_MODE_CBC);
$aesCipher->setKey($sessionKey);
$aesCipher->setIV("\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00");
$aesCipher->enableContinuousBuffer();
$aesCipher->disablePadding();
while (!feof($fileIn)) {
    fwrite($fileOut, $aesCipher->decrypt(fread($fileIn, MY_BUFFER_SIZE)));
}
```